# Multiply Verify Callbacks/getContext Calls in ssl server/client examples

Tags: python, ssl, twisted

when testing the twisted SSL Server/Client examples (https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.0.0/core/howto/ssl.html; Server with Certificates and Clients with Certificate) I noticed that on the server side the 'verifyCallback' method is called twice, and on the client side the 'getContext' of CtxFactory as well. Even is I use a Netty Implementation of the Client or Server, in Python the behavior still is the same. (verifiyCallback or getContext are called twice)

Why is this the case? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`verifyCallback` is called once for each certificate in the certificate *chain* presented by the peer.  If it is being called twice in your testing, then the certificate presented by the client is probably signed by an intermediate certificate which is itself signed by a widely recognized root certificate authority certificate.

`getContext` will be called whenever a new SSL connection is being set up, either on the client or the server.

Without seeing the actual code *and* the certificate you're testing with, it's hard to say with complete confidence that these behaviors explain what you're seeing, but it seems likely.